# Add AJAX action on item created (appended) by AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a AJAX call to filter items which user has been searched. This Ajax call appends the div with some content including the submit button (and form) to add that specified item in favorites. This adding works before filtering results, but when I do filtering with AJAX, button does not work anymore. It just redirects me to home page.

This is AJAX for sorting the results:

```
$(".ajax-form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "{{ url('addFavorites') }}",
        dataType: "json",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if(data.status == 'failedd'){
              swal("Error!", "You have already added this campaign to favorites! If you want to remove it, go to your Favorites list page", "error")
            }
            else{
            swal("Success!", "You added the campaign "+ data.idCampaign + " to favorites!", "success")
          }
        },
        error: function(data){
            swal("Error!", "error")
        },
        complete: function (data) {
     }
    });
});
```

This is AJAX for adding item to favorites:

```
  $(".test").change(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "{{ url('searchFilter') }}",
        dataType: "json",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if(data.status == 'failedd'){
              swal("Error!", "Error with filtering!", "error")
            }
            else{
            $('.myDiv').empty();
            $.each(data.idUser.matches, function(index, element) {
    $('.myDiv').prepend('<div class="row" style="border:1px solid #b5b5b5;margin-bottom:20px">'+
 '{!! Form::open(['class' => 'ajax-form', 'style' => 'float:right']) !!}'+
 '<input type="hidden" name = "idUser" id="idUser" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}">'+
 '<input type="hidden" name = "idCampaign" id="idCampaign" value="'+element.attrs.sid+'">'+
 '<button type="submit" id="test"><img align="right"  src="{{ asset('/img/icon_add_fav.png')}}"></button>'+
 '{!! Form::close() !!}</div>'});


          }
        },
        error: function(data){

        },
        complete: function (data) {
     }
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

I've figured out that when I filter results, the ID of items is not changing. Ajax renders only one id...

Answer (score 0):

Write your AJAX addFavorites code inside function. Like below :

```
function insertFavorites()
{
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "{{ url('addFavorites') }}",
        dataType: "json",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if(data.status == 'failedd'){
              swal("Error!", "You have already added this campaign to favorites! If you want to remove it, go to your Favorites list page", "error")
            }
            else{
            swal("Success!", "You added the campaign "+ data.idCampaign + " to favorites!", "success")
          }
        },
        error: function(data){
            swal("Error!", "error")
        },
        complete: function (data) {
     }
    });
   return false;
}
```

Call the function when user click submit button. Like below

Note : Have changed the button type from "submit" to "button"

```
<button type="button" id="test"><img align="right"  src="{{ asset('/img/icon_add_fav.png')}}" onclick="insertFavorites()"></button>
```

Because Jquery .submit, .click, .changes like these kind of events will not work in dynamic rendering fields.

Comment: Nope. It's not working. How can I pass my form values if there is no submit button?

Answer (score 0):

try putting `return false;` after our ajax call, will stop the form submission leading to the redirection.

Also, why are you pre-pending that whole div, why don't you render it on page load but have it hidden, then just update the value on ajax success, would give you cleaner code.